# Any pathway analysis written in snakelike

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I have RNA-Seq data and I would like to pathway analysis. Do anyone know whether any pathway analysis workflows are written in snakemake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question would fit better in the bioinformatics site: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bli I think the question is currently too broad/vague for bioinformatics SE too, but yes, if it can be made more specific, than definitely seems suitable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of pathway analysis you are referring to but according to the [documentation](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/) the official snakemake repositories seem to be located [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake).

If you can't find anything there you can at least use the examples as templates or even add to it.